# Update WooCommerce Short Description using SQL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

How can I update my wordpress database with a SQL query to move the [Description]
field into the [Short description] and then set the [Description] blank ?

Comment: Found my answer.

update mbl_posts set post_excerpt = post_content, post_content='' where post_type = 'product' and post_content <> ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never change the database structure,, if you just wanna display the short description in place of description there are hooks and filters you can use alternatively you can override the plugin file that displays the single products by creating a woocommerce directory and add tha file in the same hierarchy as in the plugin templates folder.
have a look at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
you'll also going to find the hooks and filters to do the job if you dont want to add the woocommerce directory.

you need to update the yourprefix_posts table, the products are also wordpress post you can write

```
update yourprefix_posts set post_excerpt=post_content , post_content='' where post_type='product'
```

Comment: I am not looking to change the structure, just updating the data within the field.

Comment: you need to update the yourprefix_posts table, the products are also wordpress post you can write

update  yourprefix_posts set post_excerpt=post_content , post_content='' where post_type='product'